# WPF Is there any way to get previous LOCATION in SizeChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF Window, *SizeChanged* event provides `e.PreviousSize`, it contains window size before resize:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var previousWidth = e.PreviousSize.Width;
```

Sometimes, for example, resizing with dragging the top border of window, changes Window *Location*, so I want to get also window position before resize, like this:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var previousLeft = e.PreviousLocation.Left;
    var previousTop = e.PreviousLocation.Top;
```

Do you have any good idea? thx.

Comment: yes u can do that with any DP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property that returns the previous window location so you will have to keep track of it yourself somehow. You could for example handle the LocationChanged event of the window and keep track of the locations in a queue that you then check in your SizeChanged event handler. Something like this:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Queue<Point> _locations = new Queue<Point>();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _locations.Enqueue(new Point(this.Left, this.Top));
        LocationChanged += (s, e) => _locations.Enqueue(new Point(this.Left, this.Top)); ;

        SizeChanged += (s, e) => 
        {
            if(IsLoaded)
            {
                Point lastPosition = _locations.Dequeue();
                while (lastPosition.X == this.Left && lastPosition.Y == this.Top && _locations.Count > 0)
                    lastPosition = _locations.Dequeue();

                if (_locations.Count == 0)
                    _locations.Enqueue(lastPosition);                    

                //...
            }
        };
    }
 }
```